# working with multiple tables data yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I am new with yii2 and I am having issues printing data from 2 different tables.

```
//at the end of the model
public function getTeam()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(Team::className(), ['id' => 'team_id']);
  }

// in the controller
public function actionPlay() // IRA no consigo que rule la relacion entre piloto y equipo
  {
    $player = Player::find() 
            ->leftJoin('team', 'id=team_id')
            ->orderBy('player_id')
            ->all();

    return $this->render('play', [ 'player' => $player ])
  }

Calling the view
<?= $this->render('card/play-steps', ['player'=>$player]) ?>

HTML / PHP
<span><?= $player->player_name ?></span>
<span><?= $player->team_name ?></span>
```

Seems like I dont understand the way yii2 works with table connections...
what am i missing?

thanks

Comment: Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException 
in dir/filename.php yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::__get('team_name')
making reference to <span><?= $player->team_name ?></span>

Comment: you  have to use relation try `$player->team->team_name`

Comment: thanks a lot... i guess i wasnt that far, my mistake was in $player->$team->team_name